# org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["address"] is not a JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am parsing a json using org.json in java. My json looks like:

```
{
  "address": [{
    "addressLine1": "Noida",
    "addressLine2": "UP"
  }],
  "firstName": "Achyut",
  "lastName": "khanna"
}
```

I fetch data from the java code :

```
JSONArray jsonarr= json.getJsonObject().getJSONArray("address");
String address = jsonarr.getJSONObject(0).getString("addressLine1"));
```

But it gives an exception :

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["address"] is not a JSONArray.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:578)
    at com.altametrics.io.util.test.FNParserUtilTest.testAltaMapToFNJson(FNParserUtilTest.java:513)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Why it did not recognized as JSONArray? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `json.getJsonObject()` refers to the object that should contain the `address` array?

Comment: show us rest of your code

Comment: @Thomas json.getJsonObject() is just a wrapper that gives JSONObject.

Comment: This works for me : `String json = "{\"address\":[{\"addressLine1\":\"Noida\",\"addressLine2\":\"UP\"}],\"firstName\":\"Achyut\",\"lastName\":\"khanna\"}";
  JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("address");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try following code

```
JSONObject json  = new JSONObject(str);

JSONArray jsonarr= json.getJSONArray("address");
String address = jsonarr.getJSONObject(0).getString("addressLine1");
```

Comment: Ya it works but tell me what is the problem with this if I create a map and pass map in JSONObject constructor JSONObject(map):FNHashMap map = new FNHashMap<>();
  map.put("firstName", "Achyut");
  map.put("lastName","khanna");
  FNHashMap address = new FNHashMap<>();
  address.put("addressLine1","Noida");
  address.put("addressLine2","UP");  
 
  FNArrayList list = new FNArrayList<>();  
  list.add(address);
  map.put("address",list);

Comment: what is "json" variable from json.getJsonObject().getJSONArray("address") in your example? it looks like you refers to different object

Comment: it is working when I create object using new JSONObject(map.toString()) but why it is not working for new JSONString(map) it is unpredicted yet.

Comment: Maybe because it is unclear what the Object type is of the map?
And without knowing what your 'json' from `json.getJsonObject().getJSONArray("address")` refers to, it is hard to determine what is going wrong there. Although according to the Javadocs, getJsonObject expects a String key as parameter. And it should be called on a JsonObject.

Comment: @Johanneke json is JSONObject reference that is sure.

Comment: Ok. Maybe in the future just add a little more code to your question so people can see for themselves. As for the FNHashMap failing, I don't know what an FNHashMap is, and it looks like a generic type. Maybe that's why it can't be serialized. And are you sure it is a subclass of java.util.Map? Or is it a bean?

Comment: @Johanneke Thanks !! for suggestion, It is just a Map . I thought the problem is in the formatting of JSON.

Comment: Your json looks fine to me, but you can always check using a validator, the following was my first hit on googling 'json validator': http://jsonlint.com/
According to that site, your json is indeed valid.